# Modificar Tooltip Report Viewer

Tags: javascript, .net-core, reportviewer

estoy trabajando con Bold Reports Viewer y necesito modificar el tooltip de los parámetros (realmente no se si se pueda, ya que he buscado en varias partes información, sobretodo en la información oficial).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así aparece cuando selecciono todos los registros, cosa que disminuye la visualidad para abrir y filtrar por otro nombre, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna manera para que no salga.

Saludos y gracias de ante mano